# Spark SQL query history

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to get a list of Spark SQL queries executed by various users in a Hadoop cluster?
For example, is there any log file where a Spark application stores the query in string format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Spark History Server (port 18080 by default). If you have `spark.eventLog.enabled`,`spark.eventLog.dir` configured and Spark HS is running -  you can check what Spark apps have been executed on your cluster. Each job there might contain SQL tab in UI where you can see SQL queries. But there are no single place or log file which stores them all.